# Can't see seattle.master in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

When I view the masterpages of my top-level site collection in SharePoint Designer 2013, I don't see seattle.master. I do however see seattle.html and seattle.preview.

When I browse the masterpages in SharePoint itself (_catalogs/masterpage) I see all three.

Can anyone explain this?

Site Collection is SharePoint Online 2013 (upgraded from 2010).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see seattle.master, I tested this on SharePoint 2013 online and it shows all the master pages. Sometimes, a corrupt file inside a library can cause that issue.

If you can't see it using the 'Master Pages' left nav, 
try navigating to it using 'All Files' > '_catalogs' > 'masterpage'.